# What Collection to use when both values are keys

Tags: c#, optimization, collections

I am looking for the right collection to use for the following situation:

Each Camping is unique
Each Child is unique but does not have to be in a Camping.
in code I would build this as:

```
Dictionary<Camping, List<Child>> list = new Dictionary<Camping, List<Child>>()
```

then for every child which is in Camping

```
private void AddChildToCamping(Camping camping, Child child)
    {
        if (!list .ContainsKey(camping))
        {
            list .Add(camping, new List<string>());
        }
        list[camping].Add(child);
    }
```

But later on we need to quickly see if a Child is in a Camping and if so what camping the Child is in.
With the above code this would mean looping through the complete list of Campings and List of Child.

```
bool foundInCamping = false;
foreach (Camping key in list.Keys)
{
    List<Child> children;
    bool ok = list.TryGetValue(key, out children);
    if (ok)
    {
        if (children.Contains(targetChild))
        {
            foundInCamping = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution is to have a second dictionary mapping from `Child` to `Camping`: `Dictionary<Child, Camping>`

Answer (score 0):

I use the following extension method for exactly this:

```
    public static KeyType[] ReverseLookup<KeyType, ValueType>(this Dictionary<KeyType, ValueType> subject, object lookupValue)
       // where KeyType : class
        where ValueType : class
    {
        var channels =
            from KeyValuePair<KeyType, ValueType> dcPair in subject
            where dcPair.Value == lookupValue
            select dcPair.Key;

        return channels.ToArray();
    }
```

Note that although each key can appear only once, there is nothing stopping one value being with more than one key, hence you get ketype[] back.

Usage:
   Keytype[] myKeys[] = myDictionary.ReverseLookup(myValue);

If you want a one to one mapping dictionary, I think you're going to have to write your own version...

Comment: That doesn't eliminate the looping the OP wants to get rid of. You will still have O(n) instead of O(1).

Comment: @Daniel, True, this wouldn't adjust the performance, but provides a neater way of accessing the information, which is how I interpreted the question.

Edit - Although re-reading the original question, it would still leave a loop of the original children...

Comment: Well, i intended what you both mentioned. Performance + a neater way